# Mat-select changing value does not propagate through two-way binding

Tags: angular, angular-material, two-way-binding

On the html side I have:

```
    <mat-select #footageSelects [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[element.id]">
      <ng-container *ngFor='let opt of element.items; index as index'>
        <mat-option [value]="opt">{{opt.label}}
        </mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
```

On the ts side I have:

```
@ViewChildren('footageSelects') _footageSelects: QueryList<ElementRef>;
....

this._footageSelects.toArray().map(x => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        //sets a value in the select if not defined or no more in the options
        if (!x['options'].some(y => y['value'] === x['value'])) {
            x['value'] = x["options"]["first"]["value"];
        }
    });
});
```

This code describes a list of `mat-select` components, which can get updated if the selected value is no more in the list of their respective possible options. My issue is that each one of these is linked by two-way binding to entries of an object `selectedItems`, but when assigning `x['value'] = ...` the new value does not propagate in `selectedItems`. Is not easy to change directly the dictionary in the snippet above as I don't have the relevant key. Is there a method other than `x['value'] = ...` that would preserve the double binding here?

Here is an example of the behaviour I am pointing at:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdsywh

Comment: so basically need an event which gets called after MatSelection changed?

Comment: as in `(selectionChange)` binding?

Comment: I just tried and (selectionChange) does not get triggered when updating with `x['value'] = ...`. Is there another listener I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you provide objects as values to your options.

If you do so, you have to provide a custom comparison to your select, [as explained in the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection)

```html
<mat-select #footageSelects [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[element.id]" [compareWith]="customCompare">
  <ng-container *ngFor='let opt of element.items; index as index'>
    <mat-option [value]="opt">{{opt.label}}
    </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

```js
customCompare(o1, o2) {
  return o1.id === o2.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have added `customCompare(o1, o2) {return o1 && o2 && o1.label === o2.label;}` but the behaviour has not changed, the value is not carried inside `selectedItems`.

Comment: By playing with it you can see that it is required to change both `x.value` and `elementObj` when changing value on the typescript side. Just like if the two were not binded.

Comment: Sorry know this is old just wanted to add more context. 
Had a similar issue. Everything worked before [(ngModel)] was added and then it just stopped working silently after adding ngmodel code. I was confused, it was a non intuitve break imo.